# How to draw a snake in opengl?

Tags: opengl

I am doing a snake and ladder game in VC++ using opengl.
I think i can draw a snake using arc and line. But i don't have an idea of how to do it in opengl. Can anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62540/learning-opengl

Answer (score 1):

Arc must be broken into small line segments manually. GL can render points, lines, triangles, quads and polygons only.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at spline interpolation, e.g. Bezier splines, B-splines etc.

Comment: I think you don't need spline interpolation to draw something akin to the original snake game.

Comment: Well, I don't know this game and just did a quick Google image search, but jugding from the images I've seen the snakes are too irregular to draw them only with arcs and straight lines.